# get values regarding values in another column

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select all user values where status is `review` (there are four of them: `sky - earth - sea - sun`).

```
$stmt = $db->query("select user from posts where status = 'review'");
$rows = $stmt->fetch();
foreach ($rows as $row){
    echo $row . '<br>';
}
```

Result:

```
sky
sky
```

I need:

```
sky
earth
sea
sun
```

Any help?

Comment: @vasek, I can't see the difference comparing to my query !

Comment: @vasek What's the difference?

Comment: @vasek, the same result. btw, all four values are already distinct.

Comment: Add your table structure with data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are querying for multiple records. `$rows=$stmt->fetch()` will get only one record at a time so you need to go with while loop for get each records matching with your codition.

Try this:

```
while ($rows = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $rows['user'] . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$stmt = $db->query("select user from posts where status = 'review'");
while ($rows = $stmt ->fetch_object()) {
    echo $rows->user . '<br>';
}
```

here updated answer

Comment: `Notice: Array to string conversion...`

Comment: while ($rows = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $rows->user . '<br>';
}

Comment: i updated the answer by adding  echo $rows->user . '<br>'; instead of  echo $rows['user'] . '<br>';